# Bring a new function into a closure

Tags: javascript, function, scope, closures

I've read a lot about closures and I use them regularly however I've found a case I don't understand.
Why isn't the hello variable accessible to my function I'm passing to test? Shouldn't it find it as it looks through the scope change?
My code:

```
(function($){
    var hello="hello world"
    $.test=function(a){
        alert(hello+" 1")
        a()}
})(this)
test(function(){alert(hello+" 2")})
```

Comment: What you seem to expect is *dynamic scope* (inheriting from the caller), but Javascript has *lexical scope* (inherited as written).

Comment: please don't add "solved" in title, the green check on answer indicated that you found a solution

Comment: Sorry, I use a screen reader and didn't know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript uses [lexical scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope) (*hat tip to  deceze*). Scope is determined by where a function is **defined** not by where it is passed or where it is called from.

If you want a function to have access to data in a variable from the scope it is passed to, you need to define it so it takes an argument, and then you need to pass the data.

```js
"use strict";
(function($) {
  var hello = "hello world"
  $.test = function(a) {
    alert(hello + " 1")
    a(hello);
  }
})(this);
test(function(passed_data) {
  alert(passed_data + " 2")
});
```

This is a common design pattern. See [the Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for instance:

> ```
> myFirstPromise.then((successMessage) => {
>   // successMessage is whatever we passed in the resolve(...) function above.
>   // It doesn't have to be a string, but if it is only a succeed message, it probably will be.
>   console.log("Yay! " + successMessage);
> });
> ```

Note how the function passed to `then()` takes an argument which provides the data it is going to work on.

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept but it's saying I got to weight 5 minutes